# How can I display the Max (DMax) of a Field on an MS Access Report?

Tags: ms-access, max, ms-access-2013

**Background:**

I have a table, "Table A", with a single field, "F1".  F1 is a date field, and holds a range of dates.

I have a report that displays data from my other tables, but I need to display the most recent (max) date from Table A in the report header.

How I'm currently using a TEXT BOX to display the date.  In the text box, I have the formula:

```
=DMax([Placement_File_Date].[F1])
```

**My Issue:**

When I try to use the code above, I get the error:

> The expression you have entered has a function containing the wrong
>   number of arguments.

I've also tried:

```
=Max([Placement_File_Date].[F1])
```

This doesn't give an error, but whenever the report runs the user is prompted to enter a value rather than it pulling from the table.

I know this has to be a simple fix that I'm just not seeing. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The expression you have entered has a function containing the wrong
>   number of arguments

So why not look up the documentation for the syntax of DMax?

Anyway, this is how:

```
=DMax("[F1]","[Placement_File_Date]")
```